xterm.js customKeyEventHandler executes twice in NextJS app
I'm integrating xterm.js into a NextJS application custom hook. I have attached a custom key event handler to the the xterm Terminal instance, so that I can handle custom behaviour such as Backspace and Delete keyboard events.
// useTerminal.tsx
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Terminal } from "@xterm/xterm";

const useTerminal = (terminalElRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>) => {
  const termRef = useRef<Terminal | null>(null);
  const eventHandlerAttachedRef = useRef<boolean>(false); // Tracks if event handler is attached

  useEffect(() => {
    // if target DOM element exists and terminal is not yet instantiated
    if (terminalElRef.current && !termRef.current) {
      const term = new Terminal();
      termRef.current = term;

      term.open(terminalElRef.current);
      term.focus();
      term.onData((data) => term.write(data)); // Executes once.

      if (!eventHandlerAttachedRef.current) {
        console.log("attaching..."); // This is logged once.
        term.attachCustomKeyEventHandler((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
          if (["Backspace", "Delete"].includes(event.key)) {
            console.log("delete"); // This is logged twice
            term.write("\b \b"); // delete one character?
            return false; // Prevent default handling
          }

          return true; // Allow default handling for other keys
        });

        // Mark event handler as attached
        eventHandlerAttachedRef.current = true;
      }
    }

    const cleanup = () => {
      if (termRef.current) {
        termRef.current.dispose();
        termRef.current = null;
        eventHandlerAttachedRef.current = false; // Reset flag on cleanup
      }
    };

    return cleanup;
  }, [terminalElRef, eventHandlerAttachedRef]);

  return terminalElRef;
};

export default useTerminal;

// terminal.tsx

"use client";

import { useRef } from "react";
import useTerminal from "@/app/hooks/useTerminal";
import "@xterm/xterm/css/xterm.css";

function Terminal() {
  const terminalElRef = useRef(null);
  useTerminal(terminalElRef);

  return (
    <main>
      <div ref={terminalElRef} style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}></div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Terminal;

// page.tsx

import styles from "./page.module.css";

import Terminal from "@/components/terminal";

function Home () {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <Terminal />
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;


I am aware of React's strict mode double rendering behaviour when in development mode, so have tried building and starting the app and the issue persists. I have also tried using a ref to check that the custom event handler has been attached in an attempt to prevent multiple event handlers being attached.
However, the custom event handler seems to execute twice, deleting 2 characters rather than 1.

Your term.onData((data) => term.write(data)) is most likely the culprit, as it connects the line IO a second time. Its important to understand, that xtermjs maintains line IO endpoints with onData (data coming from the terminal) and write (data written to the terminal). If you do custom key handling, your line setup should look more like onData --> process(data) --> write(altered_data), where altered_data might be a simply echo of data or the result of some command (e.g. some command eval triggered on ).
